# Erro de Implementação de mysql em C retornando undefined reference

Tags: mysql, c

Boa noite pessoal, estou produzindo um sistema em C para um trabalho de faculdade, e estou implementando o ***mysql*** no código porém, mesmo tendo reconhecido a inclusão da biblioteca ***mysql.h***, ele ainda continua reconhecendo comandos no código.

Esta é a parte do código com as dependências dele e a parte do mysql (Arquivo jojo.cpp)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h/conio.h>

//#include <curses.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <time.h>

//include\mysq\mysql.h
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    
     MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

     //printf(mysql_get_client_info());
    
    system("mode 119, 31");
    
    return 0;
}
```

O retorno desse código é:

`` /tmp/ccFjkiGu.o: In function `main': ``

`` jojo.cpp:(.text+0x811): undefined reference to `mysql_init' ``

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Você está passando a lib do mysql na hora de linkar o projeto? Não basta colocar o header no código, tem que por a lib na linha de comando para que ela faça parte do executável final.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8681/101

Comment: acrescentando ao que o @Bacco comentou, ou tbm pode adicionar a pasta com as libs nas referencias para o compilador encontrar (onde fazer isso depende do compilador)